# Dynamic USERNAME_FIELD djangorestframework and simplejwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am working on a authentication application where user's can login via

```
(email or mobile) and (password or otp)
```

Framework/ Library Used

```
Django Rest Framework and djangorestframework-simplejwt
```

I am trying to add multiple claims in the jwt token getting generated.

Below is my LoginView and LoginSerializer.

View

```
class Login(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
```

Serializer

```
class LoginSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    mobile = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(allow_blank=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True)
    otp = serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        token['name'] = user.first_name
        return token

    def validate(self, attrs):
        mobile = attrs.get("mobile", None)
        email = attrs.get("email", None)
        password = attrs.get("password", None)
        otp = attrs.get("otp", None)

        user = authenticate(mobile=mobile, email=email, password=password, otp=otp)

        if user is None and self.password:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
            detail="Incorrect Username or Password.", code=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
        )

        if user.is_active:
            refresh = self.get_token(user)
            data = dict()
            data['refresh'] = str(refresh)
            data['access'] = str(refresh.access_token)
            return data

        if user.is_locked:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
            detail="Account Locked. Contact Support.", code=HTTP_423_LOCKED
        )

        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            detail="User Account is Deactivated.", 
code=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
    )
```

But i am getting email can't be blank error when sending a valid phone number and password in request. This is because of TokenObtainPairSerializer which checks for User.USERNAME_FIELD (which in my case is email.)

How can i handle this situation or get it working ?